# Allow using composite as function argument in struct

Tags: go, composition

Let's say I'm making something like a game engine.

I need an GameObject struct which defines some event handlers:

```
type GameObject struct {
    transform        Transform
    animatedMesh     AnimatedMesh
    updateHandler    func(self GameObjectGetter)
    onCreateHandler  func(self GameObjectGetter)
    onDestroyHandler func(self GameObjectGetter)
}


func (g GameObject)getGameObject() GameObject {
    return g
 }

 type GameObjectGetter interface {
    getGameObject() GameObject
 }
```

Then, when I'm initializing some concrete GameObject, I want to define a handler as a custom function:

```
g.updateHandler = func(self FishGameObject) {  // Error here
    self.tailMotionSpeed = self.boid.acceleration.Normalize().Len()
}
```

Note here that `tailMotionSpeed` and `boid` aren't members of GameObject. They're members of struct `FishGameObject` which has some custom properties and anonymous GameObject:

```
type FishGameObject struct {
    leftFinPosition  float32
    rightFinPosition float32
    tailMotionSpeed  float32
    boid             Boid
    GameObject
}
```

I'm getting an error `self.tailMotionSpeed undefined (type GameObjectGetter has no field or method tailMotionSpeed)` if I specify argument as GameObjectGetter, and also I'm getting an error `cannot use handler (variable of type func(self FishGameObject)) as func(self GameObjectGetter) value in struct literal` if I specify argument as FishGameObject. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible in Go in the way you are trying to do. However, you can do this:

Define `GameObject` as an interface:

```
type GameObject interface {
   GetTransform() *Transform
   GetAnimatedMesh() *AnimatedMesh
   SetUpdateHandler(func(GameObject))
   UpdateHandler() func(GameObject)
   ...
}
```

The you can define a `BaseGameObject`:

```
type BaseGameObject struct {
    transform        Transform
    animatedMesh     AnimatedMesh
    updateHandler    func(GameObject)
    onCreateHandler  func(GameObject)
    onDestroyHandler func(GameObject) 
}
```

Define all the methods so `BaseGameObject` is a `GameObject`.

Then, define `FishGameObject` as you did, but

```
fish.SetUpdateHandler(func(self GameObject) {  
    fish:=self.(*FishGameObject)
     ...
   })
```

You also should use pointer receivers for all the methods.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer. But why should I always use pointer receivers? I thought it is only needed in cases when I need to modify structure from inside of a method or in special cases when the object itself must be always operated directly (for example, if it is a mutex)

Comment: The update handler is modifying the struct in the example you gave.